# Disable all Pylint warnings for a file

Tags: python, pylint

We are using Pylint within our build system.

We have a Python package within our code base that has throwaway code, and I'd like to disable all warnings for a module temporarily so I can stop bugging the other devs with these superfluous messages. Is there an easy way to `pylint: disable` all warnings for a module?

Answer (score 202, accepted):

From the [Pylint FAQ](https://pylint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#how-can-i-tell-pylint-to-never-check-a-given-module):

With Pylint < 0.25, add

```
# pylint: disable-all
```

at the beginning of the module.

Pylint 0.26.1 and up have renamed that directive to

```
# pylint: skip-file
```

(but the first version will be kept for backward compatibility).

In order to ease finding which modules are ignored a *information*-level message I0013 is emitted. With recent versions of Pylint, if you use the old syntax, an additional I0014 message is emitted.

Comment: Note: this will disable all warnings and *all errors*. If you are looking for a way to disable *only* warnings, see my answer on this page.

Answer (score 57):

Pylint has [five "categories" for messages](https://pylint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/output.html#source-code-analysis-section) (of which I'm aware).

These categories were very obvious in the past, but the numbered Pylint messages have now been replaced by names. For example, [`C0302`](http://pylint-messages.wikidot.com/messages:c0302) is now `too-many-lines`. But the 'C' tells us that `too-many-lines` is a *Convention* message. This is confusing, because *Convention* messages frequently just show up as a warning, since many systems (such as [Syntastic](https://github.com/vim-syntastic/syntastic)) seem to classify everything as either a warning or an error. However, the Pylint report still breaks things down into these categories, so it's still definitely supported.

Your question specifically refers to *Warnings*, and all Pylint *Warning* message names start with 'W'.

It was a bit difficult for me to track this down, but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3125333/disable-all-pylint-convention-messages) eventually led me to the answer. Pylint still supports disabling entire categories of messages. So, to disable all *Warnings*, you would do:

```
disable=W
```

This can be used at the command-line:

```
$ pylint --disable=W myfile.py
```

Or, you can put it in your *pylintrc* file:

```
[MESSAGES CONTROL]
disable=W
```

*Note: you may already have the `disable` option in your rc file, in which case you should append the 'W' to this list.*

Or, you can put it inline in your code, where it will work for the scope into which it is placed:

```
# pylint: disable=W
```

To disable it for an entire file, it's best to put it at the very top of the file. However, even at the very top of the file, I found I was still getting the `trailing-newlines` warning message (technically a *convention* warning, but I'm getting to that).

In my case, I had a library written by someone from long ago. It worked well, so there was really no need to worry about modern Python convention, etc. All I really cared about were the errors that would likely break my code.

My solution was to disable all the *Warning*, *Convention*, and *Refactoring* messages for this one file only by placing the following Pylint command on the first line:

```
# pylint: disable=W,C,R
```

Aside from the aforementioned message for trailing newlines, this did exactly what I needed.

Comment: ``# pylint: disable=W,C,R``, good one to use at the end of a line

Answer (score 33):

Yes, you can specify `# pylint: skip-file` in the file, but it is bad practice to disable all warnings for a file.

If you want to disable specific warnings only, this can be done by adding a comment such as `# pylint: disable=message-name` to disable the specified message for the remainder of the file, or at least until `# pylint: enable=message-name`.

Example:

```
# pylint: disable=no-member
class C123:
    def __init__(self):
        self.foo_x = self.bar_x
# pylint: enable=no-member

class C456:
    def __init__(self):
        self.foo_x = self.bar_x
```

Comment: To avoid being told that a specific warning has been disabled like this `disable=locally-disabled` can be added to the pylintrc.

Answer (score 7):

Another option is to use the `--ignore` command line option to skip analysis for some files.

Answer (score 1):

My use case is to run `pylint *.py` to process all files in a directory, except that I want to skip one particular file.

Adding `# pylint: skip-file` caused Pylint to fail with `I:  8, 0: Ignoring entire file (file-ignored)`. Adding `# pylint: disable=file-ignored` does not fix that. Presumably, it's a global error rather than a file-specific one.

The solution was to include `--disable=file-ignored` in the Pylint command options. It took way too long to figure this out; there shouldn't be a `file-ignored` error when you explicitly ignore a file.

Comment: More ideally, put it in a `pylintrc` config file, not in a command option.

Answer (score 1):

I just did this for pytest tests organised in to classes and it may be useful to someone. These were throwing up lots of errors but I like the class based structure when I'm running in the cli.

I add this below imports on all my test files and it seems to work. Might be nicer to do it once for the test directory if anyone knows the solution for that, but I don't like to ignore for the whole repo if I can avoid it

```
    # Disable pylint errors for tests organised into classes
    # pylint: disable=no-self-use too-few-public-methods
    # Disable pylint errors for pytest fixtures
    # pylint: disable=unused-argument invalid-name
```

Using it twice didn't break anything, I checked to make sure.  Initially I tried brackets for a 2 line disable but that didn't work. I didn't need commas so removed them.

If anyone knows of a decorator that can mark organisational test classes equivalent to @dataclass let me know.