# Disable pylint for a single file in vim

Tags: vim, pylint

I'd like to disable the pylint plugin for a single file in vim.  I don't want to permanently disable pylint for the file, which is what [adding a comment blocking pylint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10238473/pylint-disable-all-warnings-for-a-file) would do.

The problem is that every time I save with `:w`, there is a ~5 second lag before I am able to edit the file again.  As far as I can tell, pylint is causing this lag.

Answer (score 4):

I use the vim plugin [python-mode](https://github.com/klen/python-mode)

Reading `:help pymode`, under section 4. Commands:

```
:PyLintToggle                                                   
    Enable, disable pylint

:PyLint                                                        
    Check current buffer
```

In your `.vimrc` file, you can add:

```
let g:pymode_lint_write = 0       "turn off running pylint on file save
let mapleader = ","
nnoremap <leader>p :PyLint<cr>    "pressing ,p will run plyint on current buffer
```

Afterwhich, pressing `,p` in normal mode will run pylint on the current buffer, and autosaving any `.py` file will not trigger a pylint check unless `:PyLintToggle` is run.

Comment: For binding pylint the name was slightly different for me: nnoremap <leader>p :PymodeLint<cr>