# Pylintrc config to only show errors

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, pylint, pylintrc

I can't find a simple `~/.pylintrc` file for ignoring everything but errors.

Currently I have it set to this:

```
[MESSAGES CONTROL]
disable=W
```

From this [similar stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10238473/pylint-disable-all-warnings-for-a-file). In theory this should remove warnings but it doesn't work for me, even after reloading window.

I want only errors to be shown (in red) not warnings (in green)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was trying to solve the same thing! Your post helped me on the trail.

pylint has [several categories of checks](http://pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/user_guide/message-control.html):

> - C convention related checks
> - R refactoring related checks
> - W various warnings
> - E errors, for probable bugs in the code
> - F fatal, if an error occurred which prevented pylint from doing further processing.

So, if you want to block everything except E and F, in ~/.pylintrc do:

```
[MESSAGES CONTROL]
disable=C,R,W
```