# How can I disable a pylint message via pyproject.toml for a specific file?

Tags: python, pylint, pyproject.toml

I'm encountering the `too-many-instance-attributes` pylint error in multiple files
and I want to disable this message only for one file `my_project/runner/runner.py`.
Is it possible to do this in the poetry `pyproject.toml` file?

```
pylint my_project

************* Module my_project.models_vi.config.hostname
my_project\models_vi\config\hostname.py:67:0: R0902: Too many instance attributes (9/7) (too-many-instance-attributes)
************* Module my_project.models_vi.config.port_descr
my_project\models_vi\config\port_descr.py:92:0: R0902: Too many instance attributes (11/7) (too-many-instance-attributes)
************* Module my_project.runner.runner
my_project\runner\runner.py:22:0: R0902: Too many instance attributes (9/7) (too-many-instance-attributes)
```

Comment: If you want to disable certain checks in one file, then the place to do that is that file. But seeing your message you might want to increase the `max-attributes` setting.

Answer (score 3):

There is the [Per File Ignore Plugin](https://github.com/christopherpickering/pylint-per-file-ignores) where you can ignore files with:

```
# Example from the plugin repository.

[tool.pylint.'MESSAGES CONTROL']
per-file-ignores = [
    "/folder_1/:missing-function-docstring,W0621,W0240,C0115",
    "file.py:C0116,E0001"
]
```

Or you can add a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10238473/disable-all-pylint-warnings-for-a-file) at the start of the module like so if you don't want or can't use plugins.

```
# runner.py
# pylint: disable=R0902
```